# program on cluster exceeds RSS memory limit

Tags: memory, cluster, fedora, memory-usage, slurm

I have been trying to run a python script on a computer cluster but keep running into a error saying that RSS memory limit exceeded.
I am using this program to analyse a data set consisting of around 40000 cases. I have tried it on my pc for 1000 elements and it seems to be using a very small amount of memory. The System monitor tool on Fedora shows around %23 memory usage for my pc which is equivalent to 1.7gb (mainly used by the OS itself) but, when I run it on cluster the RSS memory exceeds 14gb.

I have no idea whats happening and why there is such a difference in memory usage between my pc and cluster. Any help is appreciated.